# MySQL: WHERE IN() limited to one row peer argument

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, where-in

I've a MySQL table like this: `id | reference_id | name`

And I wish to get rows `WHERE` reference_id is `IN` a certain list of values: `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE reference_id IN(2,3);`

The problem is that the table will contain data like:

```
id | reference_id | name

1  | 1            | nameA
2  | 2            | nameB
3  | 2            | nameC
4  | 3            | nameD
```

And by running the query I'll get a result set like:

```
id | reference_id | name

2  | 2            | nameB
3  | 2            | nameC
4  | 3            | nameD
```

Is there a way I can tell MySQL to only return ONE value peer IN argument? Meaning, I would like a result set like:

```
id | reference_id | name

3  | 2            | nameC
4  | 3            | nameD
```

Comment: Why `nameC`? Why not `nameB` for `reference_id=2`?

Comment: Use a UNION, eliminate the IN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6412b/2

```
SELECT `table1`.* 
FROM `table1` 
LEFT JOIN `table1` t
ON `table1`.reference_id  = t.reference_id 
 AND `table1`.id<t.id
WHERE `table1`.reference_id IN(2,3)
  AND t.id IS NULL
GROUP BY `table1`.reference_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from your_table
where id in
(
  select max(id)
  from your_table
  where reference_id in (2,3)
  group by reference_id
)
```

Comment: Yeah... I was trying to avoid a sub-query because of the performance impact. Thanks for the answer anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is a variable:

```
select  id,
        @reference_id:=reference_id as reference_id,
        name
from    table1 cross join (select @rn:=0,@reference_id:='') r
where   @rn:=case when @reference_id=reference_id
                  then @rn+1 else 1 end = 1
    and reference_id in (2,3)
order by reference_id
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6412b/9/0